# I don't even know what infile > outfile means. How am I supposed to use it?

Tags: python, shell, command-line, file-io

I don't know how to use Python, and I'm trying to use a script on a document. I have no idea how to tell it do this!

If I just run the script, this is the message I get:

```
Use: C:\Python27\hun2html.py infile > outfile

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\hun2html.py", line 75, in <module>
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
```

I'm not sure what info is relevant to anyone who knows about this stuff, but this is the most relevant part of the code, I believe:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if not sys.argv[1:]:
        print "Use: %s infile > outfile" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(1)
    contents = open(sys.argv[1]).read()
    print hun2html(contents)
```

It's supposed to change the formatting in a document. If anyone can make sense of this stupid question, I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1):

It means that you should write the path to the file you want to use for input where infile is and the path to the file you want to store the output where outfile is. For example,

```
C:\Python27\hun2html.py C:\input.txt > C:\output.txt
```

Note that the input file is being passed as a parameter (accessed in the code by `sys.argv[1]` ) and the output is being piped, meaning that the Python prints it to standard output, but because you put the `>` character it will be redirected to the file you indicate. If you left off the `> outfile` you would see the output displayed on your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You give it the input file as the first parameter and redirect the standard output to the file where you want to write the result. For example:

```
C:\Python27\hun2html.py myfile.hun >myfile.html
```

The `>` symbols tells it that whatever gets printed to the standard output will get written to a file, instead of the console. There is also `<` which will read a file to the standard input.

Comment: The redirection is a feature if the shell (in your case, apparently `cmd.exe`) rather than of Python. The error message comes from Python, though, and is unrelated to the redirection. Apparently you tried to invoke the script without an argument; you would specify the name of a file whose contents you want to process instead of "infile", and the name of a new file where you want the results instead of "outfile".

Comment: Thank you. I did not expect such helpfulness.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a document named `input.doc`. If you run `hun2html.py input.doc` it will display the output to that terminal.

However, since you want to have the output in another file you'll have to **redirect** the output to a file. That's where `> outfile` comes into play. If you want to save the output in `output.html`, you'll have to do this:

```
hun2html.py input.doc > output.html
```

Hope it helps.